# Subset of complex projective space and its topological properties

Tags: general-topology, complex-geometry, fundamental-groups, projective-space

Given $X$ the set of all points $[x_0,x_1,x_2] \in {{\mathbb P}_{\mathbb C} ^2}$ st $x_0x_1=0$:

a) find a compact, path-connected topological space which is homotopically equivalent to $X$;

b)compute the 1st homotopy group of $X$.

Here is my proof:

$X=A \cup B$, where $A$ is the set of points in $X$ with $x_0=0$, and similarly $B$ has $x_1=0$.
Now, if it is true that both $A$ and $B$ are omeomorphic to ${\mathbb P}_{\mathbb C} ^1$ and so to the sphere $S^2$, and given that $A\cap B$ consists of a single point, I could say that the space $X$ is homeomorphic to two tangent spheres, which are contractible to the intersection point, which is obviously both compact and path-connected, and has the trivial group consisting only of the identity as its fundamental group.

I am not sure of the correctness of the proof because of the assumption that $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic to two tangent spheres; moreover I have little general knowledge about complex projective spaces, so I fear I could have made some other errors.

Comment: I guess $A$ and $B$ are *not* contractible to the intersection point.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Why? $A$ and $B$ are not each homeomorphic to $S^2$?

Comment: How can we contract $S^2$ to a point?